# javascript findIndex callback arguments

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript.

I'm trying to find the index of a specific element in an array. I read about that I can use findIndex to loop through an array. But it seems that findIndex only accept three arguments: element, index and array. What if I want change the object that is used to be compared.

For example, I want for find the index of string `'b'` in array `['a','b','c']`,

```
var position = ['a','b','c'].findIndex(function(element, index, array){return element==='b'})
```

but how do I pass `'b'` as parameters that I can change to callback function

Thanks

Comment: "findIndex only accept three arguments" not really. `findIndex` accepts 2 arguments: callback and optional context. It is a callback that is being called with 3 arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the wanted character from the outside context inside the callback function:

```js
var wantedChar = 'c';
var position = ['a','b','c'].findIndex(function(element, index, array){return element===wantedChar})

console.log(position);
```

By doing so, you can wrap all that up in a function:

```js
var findPos = function(arr, char){
    return arr.findIndex(function(element, index, array){return element===char});
}
console.log(findPos(['a','b','c'], 'c'));
```

Note: as already suggested, it makes more sense to use `indexOf` when just comparing strings. The `findIndex`function in combination with a custom callback is there for more sophisticated search, e.g. when dealing with complex structured objects.

Answer (score 4):

What about `indexOf` function? You just have to pass one argument, as searched element.

```js
let arr = ['a','b','c'];

console.log(arr.indexOf('b'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getPosition(){
var position = ["a","b","c"];
var a = position.indexOf("b");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getPosition()">button</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Code only answer. Add some explanation to explain why.